# how to make a link inside a clickable div redirecting to another route

Tags: css, angularjs, angular, html

How can I make a link inside a **clickable div** takes to another route, other than the entire div route?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write onclick= 'routePath'

Comment: it is angular no onclick it is `ng-click`

Answer (score 0):

You can stop **click** event propagation with **stopPropagation()**. I have created a small example to better understand. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-15uxkm)